# SEO for content inside canvas element

Tags: html, canvas, seo

I recently fount this project https://github.com/flipboard/react-canvas which uses canvas to render the whole page on mobile. The result is astonishing and performs really well. By the way, from what I know, content inside canvas elements is not seen by search engines. What is the correct way to index this content?

Answer (score 10):

Traditionally (with Flash/Silverlight sites) it has has been done by feeding search engines with alternative content that displays indexable text. I'm sure you can do the same with the canvas element.
The easiest approach being:

```
<canvas>This is what search engines actually see</canvas>
```

Comment: This answer is correct. Although Google cannot see the content of the canvas, it definitely sees and indexes the text within the <canvas>...</canvas> tags. I have tried this on my own site and if I Google a unique phrase that appears within my canvas tags then that page will appear at the top of the search results, and that search result displays the context text from the canvas tags, so it's definitely indexed. The idea is similar to using image alt text to assign meaning to images. So, you will definitely want to consider applying appropriate SEO to the text you place within the canvas tags.